# Angular mat-tab-group vs nav mat-tab-nav-bar

Tags: angular, angular-material, tabs

I'm using Angular material to create a tab component. While reviewing the documentation I notice that there are two ways to create this component: https://material.angular.io/components/tabs/overview

One option requires routing and the other option does not (I can nest a component as a directive inside the mat-tab). I'm able to achieve the same results with either of the options.

I don't quite understand in which case it would be better to use the routing option vs the non-routing option. Anyone know the pros and cons?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I don't quite understand in which case it would be better to use the routing option vs the non-routing option. Anyone know the pros and cons?

- Use `mat-tab-group` when you want users to tab between contents in a single page.
- Use `mat-tab-nav-bar` when you need a top navigation that has tab-like styling. When users click on one of the tab, it will navigate to a different route. eg, you have `Home`, `About Us`, `Contact Us`.

This is the direct quote from [Material Official site](https://material.angular.io/components/tabs/overview#tabs-and-navigation:%7E:text=While%20%3Cmat%2Dtab%2Dgroup%3E%20is%20used%20to%20switch%20between%20views%20within%20a%20single%20route%2C%20%3Cnav%20mat%2Dtab%2Dnav%2Dbar%3E%20provides%20a%20tab%2Dlike%20UI%20for%20navigating%20between%20routes.):

> While `<mat-tab-group>` is used to switch between views within a single route,
>
> `<nav mat-tab-nav-bar>` provides a tab-like UI for navigating between routes.

Comment: `<nav mat-tab-nav-bar>` won't help if you need the tabs to be at the bottom of the page?

Comment: @user12163165 To invert `mat-tab-nav-bar`'s tabs and contents, you just need to place `<mat-tab-nav-panel>` before `<nav mat-tab-nav-bar>` in your HTML. Then you need to use some CSS to make the tabs stick to the bottom of the page.